# Aligning Separate Parts of Print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to align the text in my output.

```
purch_amt = float(input('Enter Amount of Purchase'))
state_stax = purch_amt * 0.04
county_stax = purch_amt * 0.02
tax = state_stax + county_stax
totalprice = purch_amt + tax

Print("Purchase Price", "= $", %.2f % purch_amt)
Print("State Sales tax", "= $", %.2f % state_stax)
Print("County Sales tax", "= $", %.2f % county_stax)
Print("Total Tax", "= $", %.2f % tax)
Print("Total Price", "= $", %.2f % totalprice)
```

... and I want it to look like this when it is run.

```
Purchase Price    = $   100.00
State Sales tax   = $     4.00
County Sales tax  = $     2.00
Total Tax         = $     6.00
Total Price       = $   106.00
```

The only way I've found to do this is extremely complex for something that should be fairly easy.

Problem solved, Thanks!

```
purch_amt = float(input('Enter Amount of Purchase'))
state_stax = purch_amt * 0.04
county_stax = purch_amt * 0.02
tax = state_stax + county_stax
totalprice = purch_amt + tax

def justified(title, amount, titlewidth=20, amountwidth=10):
    return title.ljust(titlewidth) + " = $ " + ('%.2f' % amount).rjust(amountwidth)

print(justified('Purchase Price', purch_amt))
print(justified('State Sales Tax', state_stax))
print(justified('County Sales Tax', county_stax))
print(justified('Total Tax', tax))
print(justified('Total Price', totalprice))
```

Comment: You have several syntax errors in what you've entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String ljust, rjust, center](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ljust) are what you want for padding a string like that.

```
def justified(title, amount, titlewidth=20, amountwidth=10):
    return title.ljust(titlewidth) + " = $ " + ('%.2f' % amount).rjust(amountwidth)

print(justified('Parts', 12.45))
print(justified('Labor', 100))
print(justified('Tax', 2.5))
print(justified('Total', 114.95))
```

Comment: I'd point to some [up-to-date documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ljust). Also, `print 'foo'` needs to be replaced with `print('foo')` for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the built-in [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> column_format = "{item:20} = $ {price:>10.2f}"
>>> print(column_format.format(item="Total Tax", price=6))
Total Tax            = $       6.00
```

...etc.

Breaking this down:

- `{item}` means format the parameter named `item`
- `{item:20}` means the formatted result should have width 20 characters
- `{price:>10.2f}` means right align (`>`), width of 10 (`10`), floating point precision of 2 decimal places (`.2f`)

Incidentally, you might want to look at the [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/decimal.html) package for currency work.